# How to Create Generic Multidimensional Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array

I have a reference to the type class `Class<?>`of the generic type `Element` and I want to create a two dimensional array `Element[][]` where the second dimension `null`.  Is there a way to do this?

The code I have right now is:

```
Class<?> type = ...
int length = ...
Element[][] array = (Element[][]) Array.newInstance(type, length, 0);
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = null;
```

Is there any way to do this without the loop and the extra allocated memory?

Edit ----

The second dimension being null means that its just an array of null references to arrays of `Element`.  I am doing this so I can dynamically allocate the length of the second domension so that the arrays do not need to be the same length.  So I can do something like this:

```
array[0] = (Element[]) Array.newInstance(type, 4);
array[1] = (Element[]) Array.newInstance(type, 1);
array[2] = (Element[]) Array.newInstance(type, 3);
array[3] = null;
array[4] = null;
array[5] = (Element[]) Array.newInstance(type, 8);
```

etc..

Comment: `array[i] = null`? Maybe you want to put null in each element of the 2nd dimension? What does `Class<?>` have to do with this? Your question is unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by second dimension null?

Comment: `Element[][] array = new Element[length][];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Class<?> type = ...
int length = ...
Class<?> typeOneDimArray = Array.newInstance(type, 0).getClass();
Element[][] array = (Element[][])Array.newInstance(typeOneDimArray, length);
```

In general, if you want to create an N dimensional array, create an array of N-1 dimensional array.

Comment: This works, thank you.  It still feels odd that you have to create another array though.

Comment: I think there is no standard API to get array class from element class.  So I  create an array instance and get class of it.